# How to convert a string into integer without using ruby 'to_i' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert given string into integer without using ruby `to_i` method.

Basically, I want to know how to_i was implemented or what is the best way to do that.
Eg :

```
a = '1234'

result 
a = 1234
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can find the source here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#to_i-method

Comment: `Integer(a.delete('^0-9')) rescue 0` ...

Comment: What’s wrong with `to_i`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by following

```
2.1.0 :031 > str = "12345"
 => "12345" 
2.1.0 :032 > Integer(str) rescue 0
 => 12345
```

Comment: It throws error when I pass character in my 'str' - ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer: "1234abcd">

Comment: It will give throws an ArgumentError. So it is always better to use to_i which will not give an error even if it is not a valid integer

Answer (score 1):

Used to do it using this method in C, it might help you get an idea :

```
def too_i(number)
  return 0 if (lead = number[/^\d+/]).nil?
  lead.bytes.reduce(0) do |acc, chaar|
    # 48 is the byte code for character '0'.
    acc*10 + chaar - 48 
  end
end
too_i '123'
# => 123
too_i '123lol123'
# => 123
too_i 'abc123'
# => 0
too_i 'abcd'
# => 0
```

Comment: best answer IMO as it is the closest to doing what the question seems to be looking for: converting to integer without using `#to_i` (`Integer(str)` is not that different imo). With this you at least learn that the digits begin at 48 (zero) on the ascii chart and that to convert to integer you get the ascii value via `#bytes` and subtract 48

Answer (score 0):

To be aware what is the main difference is Integer will throw an Exception if its not a valid integer, but to_i will try to convert as much as it can and you can rescue from Integer in case its not a valid integer as following

```
str = "123"
num = Integer(str) rescue 0   # will give you 123
num = str.to_i                # will give you 123

str = "123a"
num = Integer(str) rescue 0   # will give you 0 - will throw ArgumentError in case no rescue
num = str.to_i                # will give you 123
```